# UWP - RandomAccessStream quits when the file is modified

Tags: c#, uwp, stream, .net-core, file-handling

I am trying to read the contents of a file while new lines are being added.
For that I have the following code in place.

```
using (var inputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read, StorageOpenOptions.AllowOnlyReaders))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream.AsStream()))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
            }
            streamReader.Close();
            inputStream.Dispose();
        }
```

The problem is that as soon as the file is modified the inputstream has the size 0 and the loop quits.

How do I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, this seems to work.

The important part is the oldsize variable. You need to have the if clause, or else it wont work.

```
using (var randAccessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read, StorageOpenOptions.AllowReadersAndWriters))
        using (var inputStream = randAccessStream.AsStream())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            var oldsize = randAccessStream.Size;
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (oldsize != randAccessStream.Size) //Useless but seems to fix the bug
                {
                    oldsize = randAccessStream.Size;
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }
            }

            await inputStream.FlushAsync();
            streamReader.Close();
            inputStream.Dispose();
            randAccessStream.Dispose();
        }
```